# how does pointer to structure works?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, structure

I know about pointer of variables.

```
int  x = 10;
int *ptr = &x;
```

In these expression three things involved:

1. `x` takes 2 byte of memory because it is an integer.
2. `ptr` takes 2 bytes also.
3. If memory address of `x` is 1004, then `ptr` will stores 1004.

In these example whenever we use `*ptr` in program, It give us a value which stored at memory addrs - 1004

But what happens in structure?
Let take example:

```
struct book {
int a;
int b;
}
struct book str1, str2;
struct book *ptr = &str1;
```

I have three question about this example:

1. How does `ptr` holds complete address of `str1`?
2. What is the difference between pointer to variable and pointer to complete structure in memory?
3. How many bytes `ptr` will take?
4. Do `ptr` have members? If it have members so what type of members it will have? (Pointer or variable)

and one more thing- what does with object of classes instead of it

Comment: What's `Int` actually? I don't know this from the c++ standard.

Comment: Note that the size of an int* in a 64 bit machines need 8  bytes not 4.

Comment: @HarshitPanchal _"I do not compile this code right now  ..."_ If you want concise and helpful answer post a [MCVE] please. Providinfg fanasy types isn't hlpful.

Comment: @HarshitPanchal Also note: One question per question please! Such stuff like yours isn't appropriate for the intended FAQ like format here.

Comment: @πάντα But Jesus what does it matter if i write Int instead of int, people already understand what im talking about

Comment: @HarshitPanchal _"But Jesus ..."_ Did you read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) actually? It does matter, dude.

Comment: @πάντα ok ok ok
u r expert........   and i am beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) how does ptr holds complete addrs of str1?

It holds the starting address. It doesn't need to hold a range or anything.

> 2) how would be architecture of ptr in memory?

Internally it's a 32-bit or 64-bit unsigned integer depending on the operating system bitwidth (interpreted as a pointer).

> 3) how many bytes ptr will take?

4 or 8 bytes (for a 32- or 64-bit OS).

> 4) do ptr have members? If it have members so what type of members it
>   will have? (Pointer or variable)

You can dereference the pointer using the `->` operator as in

```
int x = ptr->a;
```

Comment: Harshit appears to be using a 16-bit architecture, so `ptr` should only need 16 bits/2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

1. It holds a pointer to the structure. It also happens to be a pointer to the first element, were you to cast it to an int.
2. Pointers are physically identical, no matter their type, beyond the semantics the language gives them (which you can violate with casts). A pointer is essentially just a number representing where in a long linear set of memory the data is stored.
3. The same as any other pointer - but *that* varies depending on your system. 32 or 64 bits, 4/8 bytes, *usually*. It will be the size of `void*`.
4. The pointer does not have a member. A pointer is just a pointer. However, you can *traverse* the pointer to the structure, which has members.

All of the following give identical results:

```
str1.a = 10;
ptr->a = 10;
(*ptr).a = 10;
```

Comment: simply i mean to architecture is:
what difrence between simple variable pointer and a structure pointer.

Comment: Specifically, there is not a requirement that pointers to two different types be the same size. (It is however required that any pointer be convertible to a pointer to void.)  There is not a requirement that pointers *be* numbers; there is a requirement that pointers are *things you can do math on*; that's subtly different. That most modern compilers for common architectures *do* represent pointers as numbers of a fixed bit size is because that's convenient, not because that's a requirement of the language.

Comment: @EricLippert Standard-guaranteed or not, I have never heard of, let alone used, any system where either did not hold. I have a hard time imagining one where #2 doesn't hold. #3, `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to fit any pointer and if any pointer is mutually interchangable with `void*`, it stands to reason any pointer must be equal size and should share that size with `uintptr_t`. Different sized pointers violates void* castability. However, you are right that technically `uintptr_t` could be larger; I will make an edit to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, well, young people today with their virtual memory and 32 bit flat memory models with hardware isolation of process memory and their rap music should get off my lawn. Be very happy that you've never had to work with pointers where they could be different sizes! It's a real pain, let me tell you. I am happy to learn that this is now so far in the past that it is actually inconceivable that anyone had to deal with it.

Comment: If you want to spend some time imagining a situation where pointers vary in size depending on what they point to: consider a segmented architecture where there is an entire *megabyte* available for code but only 64K available for data. If code is always in code space and data is always in data space then a pointer to a function can be always more  bytes than a pointer to data. It would be both wasteful and slow to use code-size pointers for data.  Or, of course, vice-versa; there might be lots of data memory but very little code memory.

Comment: In such a world, a void pointer has to be big enough to hold both a code pointer and a data pointer, but it does not logically follow that a data pointer and a code pointer must be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are you really asking for here? Ptr will point to an address in memory that str1 is located in. So the value of `ptr`  will be the same as of `&str1`, however if you want to get an address of a pointer (which is usually 4 bytes) - here it is `&ptr` and it will differ from `ptr` of course.
2. As said before, pointer usually takes 4 bytes of memory.
3. Depends on architecture of your computer as said before it is usually 4 bytes.
4. Pointer can not have members pointer can point to a structure or class that has members.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about a pointer to a `struct`. Basically all pointers are just a memory adress. It is mainly when you dereference a pointer when its type matters, because if you have

```
int a;
int*  a_ptr = &a;
```

then

```
*a_prt;
```

will give you an `int`, but if you have

```
struct foo { void bar(){} };
foo a;
foo* a_ptr;
```

then

```
*a_ptr;
```

will give you a `foo`. Related to this, note that

```
a_ptr->bar();
```

is the same as

```
(*a_prt).bar();
```

The compiler can check whether `foo` really has a `bar()` which would not be possible if the type of the pointer was unknown.

Comment: I think we can defines function or methods inside classes or objects only. Not inside structs.

Comment: @HarshitPanchal there is no difference between classes and structs (besides their default acces specifier)

Comment: @HarshitPanchal there is no need for having structs and classes. I can only guess, but I think Bjarne felt that it would make sense to introduce a new name for such a drastic new concept instead of only extending what a struct can do.